# How to test UI elements using JASMINE JS FRAMEWORK?

Tags: jquery, unit-testing, backbone.js, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

How to get fixtures data (reload) again after triggering click event in JASMINE JS FRAMEWORK?

**EDITed:**

Jasmine framework is used to create testing tool for javascript apps.(**BDD - Behavior - Driven Development**).

I have developed application using backbone.js. I want to create a testing tool for that. In some UI part, I did some SHOW/HIDE div.

**How to check DOM properties(UI), whenever I making events, like Click, Hover, Blur, etc.**

How can I check when I clicked button it is SHOWing content or Hiding content using JASMINE Framework?

Comment: Can you provide some code?  And have you used https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to load the fixtures then you have to search with any of jasmine-jquery method:

```
loadFixtures("fixtures/path/fixture.html");
expect($('$(body)')).toHaveText("{YOUT_TEXT}");
```